# is it possible to use TLS 1.3 for .net 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, tls1.3

I have asp.net webform application with .net 4.7.2 is there any possibility to enable  tls 1.3 in my application.

I have tried this https://www.medo64.com/2020/05/using-tls-1-3-from-net-4-0-application/

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't have to worry about this. The link you provided talks about 4.0, but you use 4.7. Else you need to elaborate on what issue you have

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Protocols in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support) and [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)